# Using ITextSharp creates PDF successfully but difficult to open downloaded PDF

Tags: c#

I already generate a pdf using itextsharp..and save it in our local server. I want to download this pdf in another button click. Code for generate pdf is working properly.Downloading occured but some error ocuured trying to open it."Because it is either not a supportive file type,or file has been damaged

```
protected void createpdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("pdf") + "\\" + "First PDF document.pdf",     FileMode.Create);

    document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);

    writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);


    document.Open();

    document.Add(new Paragraph("Pdf Geneartion!"));


    document.Close();

    writer.Close();

    fs.Close();
}
```

Code for download pdf

```
protected void download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("pdf") + "\\" + "FirstPDFdocument1.pdf", FileMode.Create);

        document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);

        writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);



        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            document.Open();
            Response.Clear();

            Response.ContentType = "pdf/application";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PDFdocument1.pdf");

            Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
        }
        writer.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're ever writing anything to `ms`. Are you getting a 0-byte file on the other end?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks more or less correct except the `ContentType`.  It should be `application/pdf` instead of `pdf/application`. Also, as @lc points out, the `MemoryStream` does not look like it is being written to.  Try something like this instead:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);  // added
            document.Open();
            Response.Clear();

            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";  // changed
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PDFdocument1.pdf");

            Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
        }
```